# What does 'e' in raising errors do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, try-except

I've come to a lecture on my python for beginners where a certain topic wasn't explained quite well. So what does this `e` do?

```
def x(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b

    except ZeroDivisionError, e:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The caught exception is assigned to the name `e`. You can pick any valid Python identifier:

```
except ZeroDivisionError, caught_exception:
```

This lets you use the caught exception; perhaps to print the error message, or use attributes of the exception for other purposes. See the [Handling Exceptions chapter](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) of the Python tutorial.

The `except <Exception>, <name>:` syntax has been deprecated in favor of:

```
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
```

which is much more readable and avoids the confusion with the syntax to catch multiple exception types:

```
except (ZeroDivisionError, ValueError):
```

Since the function you posted otherwise doesn't use `e`, it can be safely removed altogether:

```
def x(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As ZeroDivisionError is not a very good example to explain the purpose of "e" (could be reason why it was not clear to you), I am going to explain with a different error

Exception:
In general, when a Python program encounters a situation that it can't continue (buggy code), it raises an exception. An exception is a Python object that represents an error.

On your Python interpreter if you do anything with an undefined variable (or instance), you get an error like this

```
>>> a = 1
>>> print a
1
>>> print b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
>>>
```

**NameError** is the name of Exception raised

**name 'b' is not defined** is the additional information for the raised Exception

Let us repeat the same with try and except block

```
>>> 
>>> 
>>> try:
...     print a
...     print b
... except NameError:
...     print "I got NameError"
... 
1
I got NameError
>>>
```

the output is not explicit about variable/instance causing this exception.
you may feel, you can handle this if you have access to the additional information provided by interpreter

that is where the optional argument (of *except*) "e" or whatever you want to call becomes handy

```
>>> try:
...     print a
...     print b
... except NameError, e:
...     print "I got NameError"
...     print "Addition Information is:", e
...     
... 
1
I got NameError
Addition Information is: name 'b' is not defined
>>>
```

as pointed out by others, recommend to use the following convention

```
 except NameError as e
```

Answer (score 1):

It saves the message generated by the captured error in the name `e`.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> 1/0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError, e:
...     print e
...
integer division or modulo by zero
>>>
```

You should note two things however.  First is that you do not need to use the name `e`.  You can pick whatever variable name you want.  Second, the syntax you gave has been deprecated in favor of:

```
except Exception as e:
```

---

Also, I would like to add that your particular function can be rewritten like so:

```
def x(a, b):
    return a/b if b else 0
```

Having the try/except block in there is unnecessary and having `e` is really unnecessary since the function never uses it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the new syntax:

```
except ValueError as e:
    print e
```

which reads more clearly -- you're going to give the exception a name, in this case simply `e`. See [this tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) on error handling.